# Changing Columns in JTable using JRadioButtons doesn't refresh structure

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, jradiobutton

I've removed most of my GUI to keep the code short.

I have a buttongroup of 3 JRadioButtons to select the table schema i want to display in my JTable, which is contained in a JScrollPane

I have tried to use `fireTableStructureChanged()` and`fireTableDataChanged()` as well as `JTable.repaint()` to no avail.  Can anyone help me?

Here is a simple example that runs a window with my configuration but does not update the table.

```
public class test1 implements ActionListener {

private boolean payrollActive = false;

private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
private JTable dataTable;

private Vector<String> courseColumns = new Vector<String>();
private Vector<String> courseColumnsPay = new Vector<String>();
private Vector<String> profsColumns = new Vector<String>();
private Vector<String> offSpaceColumns = new Vector<String>();

public test1() {
    //Add columns for tables
    String[] courseColsPay = {"Year", "Program", "Course", "Code", "CCCode", 
            "Weight", "Session", "Section", "Day", "STime", "FTime", 
            "BookedRM", "EnrolCap", "Description", "ProfFName", 
            "ProfLName", "ProfEmail", "Notes", "Syllabus", "Exam", 
            "CrossList", "PreReqs", "EnrolCtrls", "Shared",
            "TrackChanges", "Address", "WageType", "BasePay",
            "BenefitRate", "Budgeted", "PayAmount", 
            "MthAmount", "Term", "AccNumber", "PayAdmin", "PayableTo"};
    for (String col : courseColsPay) {
        courseColumnsPay.add(col);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        courseColumns.add(courseColsPay[i]);
    }
    String[] profCols = {"FName", "LName", "Email", "UTEmail", "Birthdate", 
            "OfficeBC", "OfficeRM", "Department", "Status", 
            "Fellowship", "OfficeStat", "PhoneNum", "HomeAddr",
            "HomePhoneNum", "Notes"};
    for (String col : profCols) {
        profsColumns.add(col);
    }
    String[] offSpaceCols = {"Building", "DeptID", "DivisionName", "BldgID", "RoomID",
            "Category", "Description", "ShareType", "DeptName",
            "Status", "SharePerc", "ShareOccupancy", "Area",
            "Fellow", "Commments", "Name", "Position",
            "Dept", "FTE", "CrossApp", "CrossPos", "CrossDept",
            "CrossFTE", "OtherOffice"};
    for (String col : offSpaceCols) {
        offSpaceColumns.add(col);
    }
    mainPanel.setSize(1260, 630);
    mainPanel.setLayout(null);

    JRadioButton coursesBtn = new JRadioButton("Courses");
    coursesBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    coursesBtn.setActionCommand("Course");
    coursesBtn.setSelected(true);
    coursesBtn.addActionListener(this);

    JRadioButton profsBtn = new JRadioButton("Professors");
    profsBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
    profsBtn.setActionCommand("Professors");
    coursesBtn.addActionListener(this);

    JRadioButton officeSpBtn = new JRadioButton("Office Spaces");
    officeSpBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    officeSpBtn.setActionCommand("Office Spaces");
    coursesBtn.addActionListener(this);

    ButtonGroup tablesBtns = new ButtonGroup();
    tablesBtns.add(coursesBtn);
    tablesBtns.add(profsBtn);
    tablesBtns.add(officeSpBtn);

    JPanel tableRadioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    tableRadioPanel.setOpaque(true);
    tableRadioPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 70);
    tableRadioPanel.add(coursesBtn);
    tableRadioPanel.add(profsBtn);
    tableRadioPanel.add(officeSpBtn);

    //table start
    DefaultTableModel coursesModel = new DefaultTableModel(courseColumns, 200);
    dataTable = new JTable(coursesModel);
    dataTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    dataTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(dataTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(160, 0, 1016, 558);
    //table code end

    mainPanel.add(tableRadioPanel);
    mainPanel.add(scrollPane);

}

public JComponent getMainPanel() {
    return mainPanel;
}

public JTable getDataTable() {
    return dataTable;
}


/**
 * Returns the list of columns for the given table
 * @param identifier the name of the table
 * @return a Vector<String> of column names
 */
public Vector<String> getColumns(String identifier) {
    switch (identifier) {
    case "Courses":
        if (payrollActive) {
            return courseColumnsPay;
        } else {
            return courseColumns;
        }
    case "Professors":
        return profsColumns;
    case "Office Spaces":
        return offSpaceColumns;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

public static void createAndShowGui() {
    test1 vicu = new test1();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Victoria University Database Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1260, 630);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(vicu.getMainPanel());
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JRadioButton targetBtn = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
    ((DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel()).
    setColumnIdentifiers(getColumns(targetBtn.getText()));
}
}
```

Comment: What about your data model has actually changed that the table should actually change?  If the data hasn't changed then why should the table?

Comment: ((DefaultTableModel) target.getDataTable().getModel()).
    setColumnIdentifiers(target.getColumns(targetBtn.getText()));

i am trying to change the column headers using this function in the listener.
I return a Vector<String> from target.getColumns(targetBtn.getText());

for use with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setColumnIdentifiers(java.util.Vector)

Comment: I wrote a simple test which (very basically) does what you code is trying to do and it works fine (without needing to use `fireXxx` methods).  Consider providing a runnable example that demonstrates your problem

Comment: Ok, thankyou, will post an edit shortly.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: I understand, and further agree with you, but my application is for a very limited scope and can do without a layout manager for my purposes, unless you think this is affecting the table's behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you are not registering an `ActionListener` to `profsBtn` or `officeSpBtn`, you keep registering to `coursesBtn`

```
JRadioButton coursesBtn = new JRadioButton("Courses");
//...
coursesBtn.addActionListener(this);

JRadioButton profsBtn = new JRadioButton("Professors");
//...
coursesBtn.addActionListener(this);

JRadioButton officeSpBtn = new JRadioButton("Office Spaces");
//...
coursesBtn.addActionListener(this);
```

Once I register the `ActionListener` to the correct buttons, it works fine

Comment: I found this simply by placing a break point in the `ActionListener`, when it didn't trip, I went back to check that the `ActionListener` was being registered.  While I won't say that sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees, this should have set of alarm bells ;)

Comment: *"I found this simply by placing a break point in the `ActionListener`,"*  Oh, you kids and your high-tech. 'break-points'!  I found out the low-tech. way, by adding a `System.out.println("Event: " + e);` statement.  This was based on my long held principle *"When in doubt, print out!"*.  But in case anybody is confused, ***using a debugger with breakpoints is more optimal.***

Comment: @AndrewThompson To much typing ;) - I actually want to see what was returned by the `getColumns` method, but never got that far ;)

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be that the code adds the listener 3 times to a single button, rather than once each to each of the 3 buttons!

> ..my application is for a very limited scope and can do without a layout manager for my purposes, unless you think this is affecting the table's behaviour?

No, not the table.  It was however causing the `emptyLabel` to be assigned no space in the layout.  Here is a robust, resizable version of the GUI.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test1 implements ActionListener {

private boolean payrollActive = false;

private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
private JTable dataTable;

private Vector<String> courseColumns = new Vector<String>();
private Vector<String> courseColumnsPay = new Vector<String>();
private Vector<String> profsColumns = new Vector<String>();
private Vector<String> offSpaceColumns = new Vector<String>();

public test1() {
    mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    //Add columns for tables
    String[] courseColsPay = {"Year", "Program", "Course", "Code", "CCCode",
            "Weight", "Session", "Section", "Day", "STime", "FTime",
            "BookedRM", "EnrolCap", "Description", "ProfFName",
            "ProfLName", "ProfEmail", "Notes", "Syllabus", "Exam",
            "CrossList", "PreReqs", "EnrolCtrls", "Shared",
            "TrackChanges", "Address", "WageType", "BasePay",
            "BenefitRate", "Budgeted", "PayAmount",
            "MthAmount", "Term", "AccNumber", "PayAdmin", "PayableTo"};
    for (String col : courseColsPay) {
        courseColumnsPay.add(col);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        courseColumns.add(courseColsPay[i]);
    }
    String[] profCols = {"FName", "LName", "Email", "UTEmail", "Birthdate",
            "OfficeBC", "OfficeRM", "Department", "Status",
            "Fellowship", "OfficeStat", "PhoneNum", "HomeAddr",
            "HomePhoneNum", "Notes"};
    for (String col : profCols) {
        profsColumns.add(col);
    }
    String[] offSpaceCols = {"Building", "DeptID", "DivisionName", "BldgID", "RoomID",
            "Category", "Description", "ShareType", "DeptName",
            "Status", "SharePerc", "ShareOccupancy", "Area",
            "Fellow", "Commments", "Name", "Position",
            "Dept", "FTE", "CrossApp", "CrossPos", "CrossDept",
            "CrossFTE", "OtherOffice"};
    for (String col : offSpaceCols) {
        offSpaceColumns.add(col);
    }

    //mainPanel.setSize(1260, 630);
    //mainPanel.setLayout(null);

    JRadioButton coursesBtn = new JRadioButton("Courses");
    coursesBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    coursesBtn.setActionCommand("Course");
    coursesBtn.setSelected(true);
    coursesBtn.addActionListener(this);

    JRadioButton profsBtn = new JRadioButton("Professors");
    profsBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
    profsBtn.setActionCommand("Professors");
    profsBtn.addActionListener(this);

    JRadioButton officeSpBtn = new JRadioButton("Office Spaces");
    officeSpBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    officeSpBtn.setActionCommand("Office Spaces");
    officeSpBtn.addActionListener(this);

    ButtonGroup tablesBtns = new ButtonGroup();
    tablesBtns.add(coursesBtn);
    tablesBtns.add(profsBtn);
    tablesBtns.add(officeSpBtn);

    JPanel tableRadioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    tableRadioPanel.add(coursesBtn);
    tableRadioPanel.add(profsBtn);
    tableRadioPanel.add(officeSpBtn);

    //table start
    DefaultTableModel coursesModel = new DefaultTableModel(courseColumns, 200);
    dataTable = new JTable(coursesModel);
    dataTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    dataTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(dataTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    //scrollPane.setBounds(160, 0, 1016, 558);
    //table code end

    JPanel gridConstrain = new JPanel();
    gridConstrain.add(tableRadioPanel);
    mainPanel.add(gridConstrain, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    mainPanel.add(scrollPane);

}

public JComponent getMainPanel() {
    return mainPanel;
}

public JTable getDataTable() {
    return dataTable;
}


/**
 * Returns the list of columns for the given table
 * @param identifier the name of the table
 * @return a Vector<String> of column names
 */
public Vector<String> getColumns(String identifier) {
    switch (identifier) {
    case "Courses":
        if (payrollActive) {
            return courseColumnsPay;
        } else {
            return courseColumns;
        }
    case "Professors":
        return profsColumns;
    case "Office Spaces":
        return offSpaceColumns;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

public static void createAndShowGui() {
    test1 vicu = new test1();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Victoria University Database Application");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("Empty Label");
    emptyLabel.setFont(emptyLabel.getFont().deriveFont(80f));
    //emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.getContentPane().add(vicu.getMainPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Event: " + e);
    JRadioButton targetBtn = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
    ((DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel()).
    setColumnIdentifiers(getColumns(targetBtn.getText()));
}
}
```